# Background task or updating location in iphone

Tags: ios, location, cllocationmanager, background-process

I want to make an application that updates users location to my remote server in every xx minute, even the application is in background
I have tried the following code

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    i=0;
    UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{ 
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask]; 
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
    bgTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(backgroundTask:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)backgroundTask:(NSTimer*)timer{

    i++;
    NSLog(@"%s  %d",__func__,i);
}
```

But the timer callback stops after around 10 minutes
How can I make an application that continuously updates current location to my server

Answer (score 3):

You're probably missing the **Background Modes** key in your app's Info.plist file:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
            <string>location</string>
    </array>
```

This lets your app access location services while in the background.

But, this type of thing has been asked many times, so also do a little browsing of [other stack overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347503/how-do-i-get-a-background-location-update-every-n-minutes-in-my-ios-application) for more information.

[Here's another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807560/requesting-iphone-location-whilst-in-background) to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can update in background only for 3 minutes.Set Capabilities-> BackgroundFetch on for more or equal than 3 fields
using following code

Call this didenterbackground or foreground

```
var time = 120
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication)
    {
        time = 180
        self.doBackgroundTask()
    }

 var timerBack  = Timer()
    func doBackgroundTask() {

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {
            self.beginBackgroundUpdateTask()


            self.timerBack = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.displayAlert), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            RunLoop.current.add(self.timerBack, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
            RunLoop.current.run()

            self.endBackgroundUpdateTask()
        }
    }
    var backgroundUpdateTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier!

    func beginBackgroundUpdateTask() {
        self.backgroundUpdateTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
            self.endBackgroundUpdateTask()
        })
    }

    func endBackgroundUpdateTask() {
        UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundUpdateTask)
        self.backgroundUpdateTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
    }
```

//Do whatever you want

```
func displayAlert{


}
```