# How to get the user location when he recieves a push notification?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

What I wanna do is upload the user location to a data base as soon as he recieves a push notification, the user shouldn't have to press any button for confirmation. Is there any way to do this?

Arturo.

Comment: You cannot do this unless the user opens your application as soon as the push notification is received.

Comment: Isn't there any way to reach that goal somehow? Any way to constantly track the device?

Comment: This strides against apples policy, so no, it can't be done.

Comment: Technically it can be do as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807560/requesting-iphone-location-whilst-in-background and actually I know published apps that do that. But as @Martol1ni this could clash with Apple's policies, check *Declaring Your App’s Supported Background Tasks* in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html